# how to include .spt files in cmake

Tags: c, assembly, cmake, cmake-modules, wind-river-workbench

I am working on an embedded project with windriver compile rhow to include the (range.spt) assembly file to compile this in to range.o. I tried the below step

```
set(FREESCALE_SPT_ASM_FLAGS "-I${APP_DIR}/radar_processing")
set(FREESCALE_SPT_ASM_FLAGS "-I${BB_COMMON_CFG_DIR}")
set(FREESCALE_SPT_ASM_FLAGS "-I${BB_COMMON_CFG_DIR}")
file(GLOB src_lookprocess  ${LOOK_PROCESSING_IMP_DIR}/*.spt)enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

If an `spt` file is assembly, you should enable the assembler for it:

```
 enable_language(ASM)
 set_source_files_properties(${ASM_SOURCES} PROPERTIES LANGUAGE ASM)
```